# Dynamically adding elements to loaded svg file

Tags: javascript, svg

After loading an svg file from InkScape I want to add new elements to the drawing, created under program control. This seems to work fine if we just change the attributes of already present elements, but new created ones, even if they appear when inspecting the DOM, do not show!

A hand-simplified SVG test file:

```
<svg id="svg8" width="1e3" height="750" version="1.1" 
 viewBox="0 0 264.58333 198.43751" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <g id="layer"><circle id="cc0" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"/></g>

</svg>
```

The javascript/html file:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/>

<script>
    function addCircle() {
        var svgDoc = document.getElementById("test");
        var svg = svgDoc.contentDocument;
        var svgns = svgDoc.namespaceURI;

        // Ok, this changes the circle to red
        var c0 = svg.getElementById("cc0");
        c0.setAttribute("fill", "#ff0000");

        var layer = svg.getElementById("layer");

        // Create a circle inside layer "g"
        var cc = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
        cc.setAttribute("cx", "50");
        cc.setAttribute("cy", "50");
        cc.setAttribute("r", "20");

        layer.appendChild(cc);
        // However it's not updating the screen
        // even if DOM shows the circle is there, inside the "g"
    }
</script></head>

<body>
<object id="test" data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<script>    
    document.onreadystatechange = function(){
       if(document.readyState === 'complete') addCircle(); }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Chrome and working from local files (ie. file://)?
Can you try it in a different browser.

Comment: I've tried both Chrome 57 and Firefox 52 in Linux/Ubuntu 16.0.4. It's not a local file but it's served by the apache server running in the same machine as the browsers. (at http://127.0.0.1/X.html)

Answer (score 2):

Its the issue with your svg namespace that you are passing to create the circle. Try this

```
var cc = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Comment: @Francisco - If my soultion helped you then could you please vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `namespaceURI` of the `<object>` element.
What you need is the one of the inner document's documentElement :

```js
function addCircle() {
  // this is the <object>
  var svgDoc = document.getElementById("test");
  var svg = svgDoc.contentDocument;
  // here get the real svg document
  var svgns = svg.documentElement.namespaceURI;
  //...
```

As [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NFKamFkbCOjiACim0DI3?p=preview) since stacksnippets® won't allow the modification of inner frames...

Comment: Your solution works wonderfully, but can you be more explicit about your own comment: "As a plunker since stacksnippets® won't allow the modification of inner frames..."  Thank you.

Comment: Stacksnippets is the stack-exchange system that allows us to have working code samples inside posts. But they do use a snadboxed iframe, which will block us from manipulating inner frames. So I gave you an external link to plunkr, which provides similar service, without this restriction.